# Apex web service to insert record with avoiding duplicates

Tags: apex, trigger, webservices

Need help in writing logic for below requirement.

I have a custom object and a web service is enabled to insert data into it from external system. Inside the service we have a logic to validate if similar record is already existing (we use multiple parameters to compare), we have to merge the new record to existing. I was able to achieve it by querying the object before insertion.

But the problem  I see is, as its a web service, external system is calling the web services in bulk at once. Thus, in some situations where similar records being called through service at same time, we are not getting records while querying to validate our conditions and duplicates are getting inserted to system.

Also, if there are any data related errors etc, I need to respond back in the web service.

Whats the best way / place to put these validations / the logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your approach you're likely to get **Query Timeout Exception** since you'll need to retrieve all records from the database to detect duplicates.

Best way would be to use declarative approach by utilizing **Matching and Duplicate rules** provided by Salesforce. Follow below steps:

1. Create a matching rule with appropriates filters to detect duplicates.
2. Create a duplicate rule and add the matching rule which you've created.
3. Once done, activate matching rule and duplicate rule.

With these simple 3 steps you can detect duplicate rules and execute actions accordingly. Refer this [Matching and duplicate rules](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/10/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_data_quality_duplicate_prevention.pdf) documentation.

Comment: this is good idea, but duplicate and matching rules don't compare records, that are in chunk of bulk transaction anyway

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy you have any link for this behavior ?

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy Recently I was consuming JSON through REST API which had a bulk of records and I was able to detect duplicate records. Can you share any link or documentation.

Comment: that had such behavior at late 2015, let me check maybe it is fixed now and I am mistaken

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy Refer this [consideration for duplicate management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_management_considerations.htm&language=en_US&type=0). Nothing is mentioned about the behavior which you highlighted in your comment.

Comment: "If you’re saving multiple records at the same time and your duplicate rules are set to Block or Alert, records within the same save aren’t compared to each other; they are only compared with records already in Salesforce. This behavior doesn't affect the Report action, and duplicate record sets include records that match other records in the same save." do I understand this correctly? What does "Report" action do ?

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy If any org uses Report action with its duplicate rules, you can run reports to analyze the quality of your data and to see how well your duplicate rules are working. That way, you can fine tune your duplicate rules if needed. Refer the page 13 from pdf which I shared in my answer.

Comment: @RohitMourya well, thanks. What do you think about this words from documentation ? "If you’re saving multiple records at the same time and your duplicate rules are set to Block or Alert, records within the same save aren’t compared to each other; they are only compared with records already in Salesforce"

Comment: Yes, Records are always compared with existing records and not among them.

Comment: @RohitMourya yes. and that is the problem for topic-starter. That is why I mentioned it in my comment

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy I believe that is how you detect duplicates. And you can always get duplicate records which were detected based on your duplicate rules by using `DataCloud` and `Database` class. It will give you matches of the records which are in salesforce and not in that API

Comment: will the duplicate rule get fired if I insert two duplicate records at once?

Comment: @Samir Yes it will fire and compare first record with existing SFDC record and it will get block once duplicate is detected. It depends on our configuration of duplicate rules. If `Block` is selected then it won't check further records and will report an error else if we select `Allow` then it will simply report the error and will insert the record.

Comment: @RohitMourya thanks for the suggestion. And, thanks #AlexanderBerehovskiy for analyzing the suggestion. We created a custom field which is set to unique and inserted  our duplicate criteria fields into it by concatenating them(field1__C+field2__C etc..), thus it throwing exception on duplicate record and we are handling the exception to merge the record.